# Ionic controllers and services

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I'm pretty new with Ionic and AngularJS. I tried to create an app but it seems that the content of app.js is wrong .

This is my code look like :

app.js

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/ListeUsers",
    views: {
          templateUrl: "templates/ListeUsers.html",
          controller: 'UsersCtrl'
    }
});
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/ListeUsers');
});
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/UserControllerIonic.js"></script>
 <script src="js/UsersServiceIonic.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

userControllerIonic.js

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services'])



.controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope,userService) {
 
 
 $scope.Users=userService.getUsers();
 
});
```

UsersServiceIonic.js

```js
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])


.factory('userService',function () {

  var Users =[];
        
        return{
   
   getUsers:function(){
    return $http.get("http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/").then(function (response) {
       users=response;
                            return users;
                        });
   },
   
   getUser : function(UserName) {
    return $http.get("http://localhost:26309/api/User/getUserByNom/" + UserName).then(function (serviceResp) {
     return serviceResp.data;
    });
   }
  }
  
})
```

ListeUsers.html

```html
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="user in Users"
               >{{user.nom}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

i can't find the problem

Comment: what's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: nothing appears , a blank page

Comment: what does the browser console say? There should be an error there pointing you in the right direction

Comment: there is no error , it's like the view can't retrieve data from the controller

Comment: Your 'otherwise' route url `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/ListeUsers');` looks incorrect. Please try if this is working: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/ListeUsers');`. Then it should load the correct state.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues you need to fix here for your app to work:

1. You need to correct he default fallback url from `/app/ListeUsers` to `/ListeUsers` because `/app/ListeUsers` path will be valid if the state was a child-state of `app`. See more details here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views
2. Your service methods are returning promises. **You cannot assign a promise to a $scope variable and expect the app to be working**. Change your controller code to use the parameter from the `.then` method callback of the returned promise as below:

   angular
      .module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services'])
      .controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope,userService) {
         userService.getUsers()
           .then(function (response) {
             $scope.Users= response;
           });
       });

Comment: Thank you so much for this complete answer but it still doesn't work , it's like the list of users is empty because the back-end project is implemented in ASP.NET with VS and am implementing the front-end with brackets so i dont know if this is the reason why i can't retrieve the data from database

Comment: Can you see the response in your Network tab in Dev tools?

Comment: This error occurs : <Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
........etc